# SOAP web service giving 500 server error using Proxy Servlet

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, soap, proxy

Hi I am trying to send a XML payload using ajax call through a proxy servlet. The url is a SOAP Web Service. The client side javascript code looks like this.

```
var sURL = "https://username:password@my11111.crm.example.com/sap/bc/srt/scs/sap/managecustomerin1?sap-vhost=my11111.crm.example.com"

$.ajax({
        url : sURL,
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

        },
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "xml",
        data : sEnv,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
        success : handleSuccessCallback,
        error : handleErrorCallback

    });
function handleSuccessCallback(data, resp){

        alert("Success: "+data);

    }

function handleErrorCallback(msg){
        alert("Error: "+msg);
    }
```

Variable sEnv is holding payload xml data for eg:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
xmlns:glob='http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global'
xmlns:a00='http://sap.com/xi/AP/CustomerExtension/BYD/A0014'
xmlns:glob1='http://sap.com/xi/AP/Globalization'>
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <glob:CustomerBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>
        <BasicMessageHeader></BasicMessageHeader>
        <Customer actionCode='01'>
            <CategoryCode>2</CategoryCode>
            <CustomerIndicator>true</CustomerIndicator>
            <LifeCycleStatusCode>2</LifeCycleStatusCode>
            <Organisation>
                <FirstLineName>SAP Madrid       </FirstLineName>
            </Organisation>
            <ABCClassificationCode>A</ABCClassificationCode>
            <AddressInformation actionCode='01' addressUsageListCompleteTransmissionIndicator='true'>
                <ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>002</ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>
                <Address actionCode='01' telephoneListCompleteTransmissionIndicator='true'>
                    <PreferredCommunicationMediumTypeCode>LET</PreferredCommunicationMediumTypeCode>
                    <EmailURI>info@sap.com</EmailURI>
                    <FacsimileFormattedNumberDescription>9111111111</FacsimileFormattedNumberDescription>
                    <WebURI>www.sap.com</WebURI>
                    <Telephone>
                        <ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>004</ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>
                        <FormattedNumberDescription>9111111111</FormattedNumberDescription>
                    </Telephone>
                    <PostalAddress>
                        <CountryCode>ES</CountryCode>
                        <CityName>Madrid</CityName>
                        <StreetPostalCode>28043</StreetPostalCode>
                        <StreetName>Torrelaguna</StreetName>
                        <HouseID>2</HouseID>
                        <POBoxDeviatingRegionCode>28</POBoxDeviatingRegionCode>
                    </PostalAddress>
                </Address>
            </AddressInformation>
            <DirectResponsibility actionCode='01'>
                <PartyRoleCode>142</PartyRoleCode>
                <EmployeeID>E1019</EmployeeID>
            </DirectResponsibility>
        </Customer>
    </glob:CustomerBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>
</soapenv:Body>
```

When I call the service using chrome flag **"--disable-web-security"** and without any proxy servlet(refer sUrl variable above), the code above works and I am able to send the payload successfully to the web service and I can see the new data added in the backend. But I don't want the chrome security flag. So I tried using a Proxy Servlet.

Now I use the URL in the ajax call like this

```
var sURL = "/tenantSystemUi5/TechProxyServletPost?username:password@https://my11111.crm.example.com/sap/bc/srt/scs/sap/managecustomerin1?sap-vhost=my11111.crm.example.com"
```

The class TechProxyServlet code snippet inside doPost() is as follows

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String logString="TECHPROXY POST : START :\n";
    try{
        String reqEncoding = request.getCharacterEncoding(); 
        if( reqEncoding == null || reqEncoding.trim().length()==0 )
            reqEncoding = "UTF-8";

        String payload = this.getDataFromStreamPost(request.getInputStream(),reqEncoding);
        String xmlStreamInput = payload;  // XML Input  
        String inputString = request.getQueryString();

        String requestURL = "";
        String userpass = "";

        if(inputString.contains("@"))   // Contains User Name and Password
        {
            String temp[] = inputString.split("@");
            userpass = temp[0];         
            requestURL = temp[1];
        }
        else
        {           
            requestURL = inputString;
        }

        String xCsrfToken = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        List<String> cookies = null;

        try {
            URL serviceUrl = new URL(requestURL);

            System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy");
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");

            logString = logString+"TECHPROXY POST URL:"+requestURL+"\n";
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) serviceUrl.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


            if(userpass.length() > 0)
            {
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", this.getBasicAuth(userpass));
            }

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset="+reqEncoding);
            connection.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", "fetch");

            connection.connect();    // SUSPECT 1

            System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE: "+connection.getResponseCode()); //SUSPECT 2

            /*This if condition results false becoz 200 != 500 :( */
            if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode())  
            {
              // Do Stuff...... like writing payload to the server
            }
            else {
                response.setStatus(connection.getResponseCode());
                response.setContentType("application/json; charset=TIS-620");
                String servletErrResponse = this.getDataFromStream(connection.getErrorStream());
                response.getWriter().println(servletErrResponse);
                logString = logString+"TECHPROXY ServletResponse XSCRF GET:ERROR:"+servletErrResponse+"\n";
            }
        }
  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(connection.getResponseCode());
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=TIS-620");
            String servletErrResponse = this.getDataFromStream(connection.getErrorStream());
            response.getWriter().println(servletErrResponse);
            logString = logString+"TECHPROXY GET ServletResponse:ERROR:"+servletErrResponse+"\n";

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logString = logString+"TECHPROXY EXCEPTION:"+e.toString()+"\n";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I request the service through the above proxy servlet, the **connection.getResponseCode()** returns a response code **500 (Internal Server Error)**. and the servletErrResponse string as

```
<soap-env:Envelope
xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
    <soap-env:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap-env:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en">Web service processing error; more details in the web service error log on provider side (UTC timestamp 20141211053452; Transaction ID 00163E087A571ED4A09EEDD46BAC158F)</faultstring>
        <detail/>
    </soap-env:Fault>
</soap-env:Body>
```

In the above servlet I'm trying to bypass access-origin control policy of browser. But I'm not able to figure out why 500 error comes. What can I do to rectify it. Right now I might not have access to server log files.
Is the line

```
connection.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", "fetch");
```

necessary?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

neo

Comment: `more details in the web service error log on provider side` ?

Comment: Actually I got the web service url from an excel-VB application and using it in a web application to check the feasibilty if I am able to send xml payload using ajax call. By disabling web security of chrome and without using any proxy, I am able to successfully send data to the server side. Right now I don't have any more details on the web service and error logs. The only thing I see is the data getting added through an web-UI whenever it is successful. No server log access shown in the web UI. :(

Comment: Before adding these 2 lines to doPost(): 

     System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy");
     System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");  

I used to get UnkownHostException:my11111.crm.example.com